# Destroying Odric, Master Tactician in response to declared attackers

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Alright, so we were playing a game and confusion was brought up.
Player 1 Attacks with 5 creatures as well as [Odric, Master Tactician](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOdric%2c%20Master%20Tactician%5d). When doing so, Odric's ability kicks in saying P1 could choose which creatures block, and who they block. In this phase, when P1 declared which of his monsters were attacking, and P2 played [Bright Reprisal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBright%20Reprisal%5d), which states "Destroy target attacking creature. Draw a card." P2 used that card to destroy Odric. So with that being said, would Odric's ability still be in effect?

Comment: Even though the answer is the same, aren't the questions asking different things? The proposed duplicate is asking specifically about bouncing a creature, not destroying it.

Comment: @SocioMatt In the end it is still about the creature leaving the battlefield and it doesn't matter where it goes to.

Comment: As a minor pedantic note, since declaring attackers and blockers does not use the stack, you can't 'respond' to either. Responding to an action is meant to interrupt that action, so your effect happens first, by the time you get priority, attackers have been declared and this process cannot be interrupted.

Answer (score 5):

Abilities written as "Whenever X, Y" are triggered abilities, they go onto the stack when the trigger condition, in this case "*Whenever Odric, Master Tactician and at least three other creatures attack*" is met, the ability's effect, in this case "*you choose which creatures block this combat and how those creatures block*" is put on the stack.

Once an ability is on the stack, changes to the board itself don't affect that ability, it is going to resolve unless countered. So unless you [Stifle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStifle%5d) the ability, removing the Odric, no matter where he goes, be that to hand, exile, graveyard or even flickered back to the board, will not stop his ability from resolving. The only change to boardstate that can affect a spell or ability on the stack is if that ability is no longer legal, say removing all targets, causing the spell or ability to fizzle (be put in the graveyard as it would resolve).

Comment: Note that this would be different if the ability said "whenever Odric attacks, if Odric and at least the other creatures are attacking, then ..."  An "if"-clause like that in a triggered ability is checked both at trigger time and at resolution, and it would therefore do nothing of Odric is removed while the ability is on stack.

Comment: @Arthur is absolutely right, an intervening if would force the check on resolution as well as the trigger. I didn't include it here because it's not relevant to the case, but it's worth knowing.

Comment: If I had a creature that granted hexproof to all of my other creatures, planeswalkers, and myself, would his ability go through then?

Comment: Odric's ability doesn't target, so it is unaffected by hexproof.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a triggered ability and not a global effect, player 1 still gets to decide, how/if players 2 blocks. Same goes for the other Odric who shares the abilities of your creatures.